# Disable root password, and eliminate sudo, on system that will only ever be orchestrated remotely?

Tags: security, sudo, password, root, su

The system in question will only ever be managed remotely using Ansible and so I'm not concerned about limiting catastrophic commands from a group of users or allowing convenient administrative access.  I'm more concerned with locking down the system against a hacker who somehow either gains console access or is able to run commands using an unknown vulnerability.  The system will also not have X installed, it is strictly headless.

The plan I've decided on (tentatively) is:

1. Disable **root** login via SSH (this is a given)
2. Eliminate `sudo` and the **wheel** group,
3. Utilize a private key for **root** login,
4. Disable the root password entirely.

**Are there any further steps I should take to lock down root access?  Or are the steps I'm taking too much**, i.e. are there unintended consequences I'm not accounting for?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** It was raised in the comments that since this system will only be orchestrated, why not just allow **root** to log in via SSH with a key?  The following might suit our use case even better since the only real use of an intermediary account in our case would be to allow a human access which can run admin commands via `sudo`. So with that in mind, what about this...

1. Eliminate our current intermediary *no-rights* user,
2. Set up SSH key for **root** user
3. Eliminate the root password with `passwd -d root`,
4. Lock down the account with `passwd -l root`,
5. *Enable* SSH access to the root user, and have orchestration system use **root** directly when logging in.

The question remaining then is, **are there other security concerns that this method raises?**

Comment: After you disable root login via ssh, how do you expect the key login to work?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I would be logging into the system via a no-rights user and then using 'su' to access the root account, but maybe I'm misunderstanding, will that method not be able to use an SSH key to log into root?  I don't mean to stop us from logging into root at all, only not as the initial connection.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I guess the question becomes, if I just eliminate passwords for these two users, is there any point in eliminating `wheel`, or am I overthinking it?

Comment: Bear in mind that your orchestration still needs to be able to become root.

Comment: @StephenKitt This is likely me overthinking it, I'd assumed that it could use `su` rather than `sudo` to become the root user, but I'm getting the feeling I've misunderstood it, and that `wheel` may be still required, but just limited to the single *no-rights* user we use to make the initial connection.

Comment: Specifically, if you disable the root password, then `su` becomes meaningless (but you don’t need `su`). You don’t need a `wheel` group, just `sudo` configured to allow the initial login user to become root. But if the only root user is Ansible, it seems to me you might as well allow Ansible to log in as root directly, using a key... (I haven’t used Ansible for a while, so I might be missing something.)

Comment: @StephenKitt I guess I hadn't considered that because every security hardening list out there always starts with *Disable root login via SSH...*. But now that you raise it in this context... I guess the only reason to use the intermediary would be to allow a human to log in and execute via sudo, but I specifically do not want that here, so this makes sense.

Comment: @oucil, even if you have just keys, you can still log in as a human with them. The thing about preventing logins directly as `root` is that you're going to get a lot of brute force password login attempts against `root` and maybe `admin` or such, but less against `oucil` or `ilkkachu`. But if someone really wants in, they can figure out the username that works, and then try to brute force the password(s). (Basically the username just becomes an additional bad "password", one that leaks more easily and has less entropy than a proper one.)

Comment: @ilkkachu The brute force attacks you're talking about would be against passwords though, not against an SSH key, so if I have `sshd` configured properly with `PasswordAuthentication no` and `PasswordAuthentication no`, what's the real impact?  Further, with fail2ban in place, we can capture those attempts and block IP's accordingly.  Only a botnet with different IP's would be able to circumvent that.

Comment: @oucil, yes, that's exactly what I mean, there's no "magic" in blocking root logins, just make sure it's not brute-forceable. You probably meant `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` on the second one, and there's `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password`, too.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yeah, sorry, I did mean `Challenge....` on the second.  And thanks for the hint on `prohibit-password`, only having just started looking at this option, I hadn't come across that yet, it's always just been set to `no` :)

Comment: Your revised step 4, `passwd -l root`, is likely to lock the account entirely. Therefore, step 3, `passwd -d root` is also wrong

Comment: @roaima I don't believe that's correct, this is directly from the man page for `passwd -l` *Note that the account is not fully locked - the user can still log in by other means of authentication such as the ssh public key authentication.*  Further, `-d` simply clears the existing password.  Then the `-l` sets the password to an invalid string unmatchable via login.  Nothing in that actually locks the account or prevents me from logging in with my key. Correct me if I'm wrong.